# How to slow down CURL requests with proxy rotating?

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping, https, proxy

I'm using `CURL` with proxy rotating:

```
$url = 'https://www.stubhub.com/';
$proxiesArray = array();
$curl = curl_init();
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($proxiesArray) - 1; $i++) {

    //CURL options.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE, CURLPROXY_HTTP);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxiesArray[$i]);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 0 );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE );
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_URL, trim($url) );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, trim($url));
    curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);

    //CURL info.
    $data = curl_exec( $curl );
    $info = curl_getinfo( $curl );
    $error = curl_error( $curl );
    $all = array($data, $info, $error);

    //If success.
    if (empty($error))  {
        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($all);
        echo '</pre>';
        break;
    }

    //Wait for 2 seconds.
    sleep(2);
}
curl_close( $curl );
```

But I'm redirected to a Recaptcha page that contains a message:

```
Due to high volume of activity from your computer, our anti-robot software has blocked your access to stubhub.com. Please solve the puzzle below and you will immediately regain access.
```

To slow the requests, I tried:

```
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_MAX_RECV_SPEED_LARGE,10);
```

Also:

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, function() {
    sleep(2);
    return 0;
});
```

But I get the same message, So how to slow down the process to be like a real request from the browser?

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is from another thing

for create request like browser , you shoud use headers in your request

for example i suggest you to add useragent in your codes and change it in every single request !

example user agent:
`User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20200101 Firefox/61.0`